# C#. How catch time critical error detected c0000374?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

At some point, there is an abnormal exit from the program, without exception.

Debug the steps programa does not work as well.

In the debug output I see the following list of posts,  which there is a message

```
Critical error detected c0000374
Critical error detected c0000374
```

Is it possible to capture a moment before this message in the debugger?

All list of posts abnormal exits

```
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x6fac) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Critical error detected c0000374
Critical error detected c0000374
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x4278) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x49d4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x48dc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x497c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x67d8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x672c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x3c64) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x25f8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x6328) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x31f0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x308c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1398) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x4fa0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x372c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x2184) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1698) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x41dc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x45cc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x3db4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x6f78) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x5fc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x522c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x6a6c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x4f94) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x31f4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x2ce4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x54d8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1fa8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[23172] D_Project.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[23172] D_Project.exe: Managed (v2.0.50727)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

here list of posts normal work in this case

```
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x6184) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x47c0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x4aa0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```